# CodeIgniter's sess_destroy doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter

I have this controller:

```
    function Logout() {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('/');
    }
```

Pretty straightforward. But it doesn't work. As simply as that - sessions are stil stored. I tried using `unset_userdata` with all my sessions (two at the moment), but it doesn't work also.

Comment: Are you declaring your sessions using CodeIgniter's session class as well? CI uses a different system to native PHP sessions, so if you declare `$_SESSION['somevar']` and try to remove it with CI's session class it won't work.

Comment: Yes, I do it in another file with `set_userdata`.

Comment: Are they being reset as soon as your default controller (`'/'`) is called, maybe? Have you tried echoing one of these session values before redirecting?

Comment: I've done this: `$this->session->sess_destroy(); print_r($this->session->all_userdata());` and it shows me all the data, like it wasn't even touched.

Comment: That's 'normal' behaviour for CodeIgniter: as the session is saved in cookies, these values are only effectively deleted on the next page load. So, using `redirect('/')` should clear these; are they still present on the default controller?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17381/discussion-between-froddd-and-tomek-buszewski)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change $config['sess_cookie_name'] with other dynamic name because sometimes same variable conflicts on your browser specially IE.

You will have to go on config folder and config.php file

go to application->config->config.php

$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session2'; // rename ci_session to other name that will resolve your issues.